# Typescript function parameter must be a `const assertion` of a number

Tags: typescript, types

How do I create a function that only accepts a `const assertion` of a number. Eg:

```
function func(arg: number as const){} // somehow do this

func(1 as const); // valid
func(1); // error
```

Is this possible?

The reason I want to do this is because I want to return a tuple of length = `arg`

I do have a type, that create a tuple of given length:

```
type TupleFromCount<
    T,
    N extends number,
    S extends T[] = [],
> = S['length'] extends N ? S : TupleFromCount<T, N, [T, ...S]>;

type temp = TupleFromCount<string, 5>;
//    ^  type temp = [string, string, string, string, string]
```

So I want to use it like this:

```
function getRecords<T extends number = 10, K>(
    page: number,
    itemsPerPage: T,
): TupleFromCount<K, T> {
    const arr: TupleFromCount<string, T> = new Array<K>(itemsPerPage);
    return arr;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't a way to require that the caller literally writes `as const` as part of the parameter.  You probably don't even really want that anyway; presumably you just want the function to require that `arg` be of a numeric [literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) instead of the `number` type.

---

The first step toward achieving this is to give the compiler a hint that you want the type of `arg` to be inferred as a numeric literal if possible... this would be more like *requesting* a `const` assertion interpretation of the input instead of *requiring* it.  There's no similar syntax like `as const` in the call signature side, (see [microsoft/TypeScript#30680](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30680) for a relevant feature request), but there are other ways to get this behavior.  You could make `func()` a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) function and have the type parameter `T` be [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) to `number`.  A type constraint like `T extends number` is a hint that the compiler should try to infer a numeric literal for `T` instead of `number`.  (See [microsoft/TypeScript#10676](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/10676) which implements and describes this behavior).

So let's try it:

```
function func<T extends number>(arg: T) { }
func(1 as const); // function func<1>(arg: 1): void
func(1); // no error, but function func<1>(arg: 1): void
```

Here the compiler infers that `T` is `1` (and not `number`) in both the `func(1 as const)` call, as well as the plain `func(1)` call.  This is probably even better than spewing errors when you call `func(1)`, right?

---

That's great, but it still doesn't prevent `number` from being passed, like this:

```
let someNumber: number = 1;
func(someNumber); // no error,
// function func<number>(arg: number): void
```

To truly prevent that, we need to get creative with our generic constraints, and employ [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html):

```
type SomeNumericLiteral 
  = 1 | 2 | 3; // just a dummy numeric literal union to make the error nice
function func<T extends (number extends T ? SomeNumericLiteral : number)>(
  arg: T) { }
```

What I've done there is to have the compiler look at `arg` and infer `T`.  It then checks that it is assignable to `number extends T ? SomeNumericLiteral : number`.  If `T` is inferred as a numeric literal, or really any type that isn't `number` or some supertype of it, then the conditional type collapses to `number`, and it behaves the same as before with just `T extends number`:

```
func(1 as const); // function func<1>(arg: 1): void
func(1); // function func<1>(arg: 1): void
```

On the other hand, if `T` is inferred as `number` or some supertype of it, then the conditional type collapses to `SomeNumericLiteral`, and `T extends SomeNumericLiteral` will fail the constraint, because `number` or some supertype does not extend `SomeNumericLiteral` by design:

```
let someNumber: number = 1;
func(someNumber); // error!
//   ~~~~~~~~~~
// Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SomeNumericLiteral'.
```

Note that I defined `SomeNumericLiteral` as `1 | 2 | 3`, but we just needed to use some  type that `number` doesn't extend to make a compiler error happen; I chose `1 | 2 | 3` since hopefully that will make the error message nicer in cases people pay close attention to it.  The usual go-to thing to write is `never` instead of `SomeNumericLiteral`, but that makes a weird message.

---

So there you go... now `func()` only accepts numeric literals and rejects `number`.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEAJAlsALkg3gWAChCkSkAzAV2HkzQHthyr4AeAFSQgA9MJgATKEmAUwAIwgAnAHwAKEJIDmALiRsAlLiQBfYqUrVZARiQgh8BlEzqA3EgD09ptVoNnrI3IUqkR9aoA3OjR+PRIDeGNbBydgOk5JSTpJABokMQpsCNdGCJZPeSVVP0Dg0KICUiQAGwhsKDpIADlRCUlVEXEpJABeXxsw91kG5tapaMdheKkk1NMBdxz3Fk62ryLhMcl-JCCQwkJdCtBIWARkACUIAEcKNElkfAqqzABPGGQAZUaIFshJNDwAAyaF4khA1V6viQAB8kAAmWFIADMdkmACsKFZTEh+KIwK9Nv9ATVQVIIUgqPRGJh4mAQABrZCYAAWyBmyWEgIgg2y1OWHG4vAEQlkq26Qr4gjUSAA-EhvqNicCyeDIR0tup1j4NFojlUIsZTOZLNY0U4+W48gVvMUdntygbmFFzYt+dbtXbSvtnqRavUfn82hqupIoUYBpV9M6Rr9Na6OZIAISDSYkAB+maz2dTTgAgkpRHxsHQyEg3h8kABycWSKtINBCOLYMxQNCKUBiWrl+JwcGQMFIUvl97IKuKuPKkFgiFVgB0BwIR0IQA)

Comment: Wow, I have never seen something like that. It's a really clever solution and this is what I was looking for too. Thanks a lot